# Java SDK mismatch with ext. native library

Tags: java

I am trying to use a ext. native library in eclipse but the program gives the following error : "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'edk': libedk.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32" .

I thought it may be because the library is 32-bit whereas my JDK is 64-bit ? Is that it , if so please tell me how to install 32-bit JDK along with 64-bit already present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I thought it may be because the library is 32-bit whereas my JDK is 64-bit ?
```

Yes, indeed.

```
please tell me how to install 32-bit JDK along with 64-bit already present
```

Well, for instance, download it from Oracle, create a directory in `/opt` where to extract it and set `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` in a custom launching script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/32bit/jdk
export JDK_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JDK_HOME/bin:$path
exec /path/to/eclipse "$@"
```

Comment: thanks , I also found that I can multiple libraries in Eclipse and then assign each project a compatible one .